# UITableView with custom UITableCells crash on leaving edit mode randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, calayer

I do have serious problems with my `UITableView`. I will describe the structure first,
because the error that happens sometimes is not obvious:

- My `UITableView` consists of different custom cells with `UIImage`s, `UIButton`s and `UITextfield`s.
- In my cells I overwrite the `layoutsubviews` method to change the appearance of the cell animated when the table enters edit mode. For example I have an `UIImage` x at a specific position and do something in `layoutsubviews` like `if(edit) x.frame = .....` so that the image x moves to the new position when table enters edit mode.
- when I enter or leave edit mode of the table sections and rows are added or deleted in animationblocks (beginupdate/endupdate)
- my table changes tableheader when entering an leaving edit mode

Now my problem:

I have no errors when adding or deleting cells / sections and no index errors everything seems to work fine. But sometimes when I LEAVE edit mode, I get an `CALayer position contains NaN` message. The error is not reproducible and seems to me happen very random.The error occurs in the animationblock between beginupdates / endupdates where I will remove rows and section in this use case (leaving edit mode)... the leave editmode is triggered a line before the animationblock ( leaving the editmode will force the cells to animate its picture and buttons to its noneeditstate frames)... so maybe the two triggered animation which happen beside make problems SOMETIMES..... because the problem happens very random I can't figure out what is the problem ? Any hint would be helpful!!

One additional thing is that when I am debugging with the device the error happens very rare. But when I am using the app on the device without debugging it happens often.

Comment: most likely you are dividing by zero somewhere. Make sure that in your calculations the divisor can never be 0.

Comment: `NaN` often comes from a division by 0. I suppose you have cells (and/or section headers) with dynamic heights? What do you do in `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath:`? (and/or `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`)

Comment: @fluchtpunkt and Jilouc both functions only return static numbers no calculations are made... i only check which celltype it is and return the specific height.....could it be possible that while i leave edit mode and the cells get animated my remove of the cells could possible crash it.. maybe because an cell which is animating will be deleted and so an element which was animating doesnt exist and so its layer has no value??